# What does て in this mean? 「そんなこと言って。」

Tags: grammar

> A「ねえ、この漫画、面白いよ。」
> B「興味ない」
> A「そんなこと言っ**て**。本当は読んでみたくてしかたがないくせに」

Is て here a contracted form of something?